# Lua : merge keys and output keys should not have repeative values in table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am having a table

```
 
test = {a= {1,2}, b= {1},c= {2,3}}
```

I want output like.

```
test_out = {ab={1,2}, bc = {1,2,3}, ac={1,2,3}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently what you want are set operations. Here is a way you can do it without any library:

```
local test = {a = {1, 2}, b = {1}, c = {2, 3}}

local keys = {}
for k,_ in pairs(test) do keys[#keys+1] = k end
table.sort(keys)

local result = {}
local t1, t2, r, found

for i=1,#keys-1 do
  for j=i+1,#keys do
    t1 = test[keys[i]]
    t2 = test[keys[j]]
    r, found = {}, {}
    for k=1,#t1 do
      found[t1[k]] = true
      r[k] = t1[k]
    end
    for k=1,#t2 do
      if not found[t2[k]] then
        r[#r+1] = t2[k]
      end
    end
    result[keys[i] .. keys[j]] = r
  end
end
```

The result is in the `result` table. If you can use a set library like `pl.Set` you can do it with less code:

```
local test = {a = {1, 2}, b = {1}, c = {2, 3}}

local keys = {}
for k,_ in pairs(test) do keys[#keys+1] = k end
table.sort(keys)

local result = {}
local Set = require "pl.Set"

for i=1,#keys-1 do
  for j=i+1,#keys do
    result[keys[i] .. keys[j]] = Set.values(
      Set(test[keys[i]]) + Set(test[keys[j]])
    )
  end
end
```